# Connect to an external Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I've a problem connecting on my free database.
I created a free mysql database on freesqldatabase.com in order to try if my php script does his job. The main purpose is to insert data from an html form (hosted in a different host let's say HOST A) into a table in the database (in HOST B). I tried many times but it says that could not connect on database.

Here's the error:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): 
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sql2.freesqldatabase.com' (110) 
in [HOST A]/core/try.php on line 6 ERROR: Could not connect. 
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sql2.freesqldatabase.com' (110)
```

So here's my PHP script:

```
    <?php

$link = mysqli_connect("sql2.freesqldatabase.com", "user", "password", "database_name");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (person_id, first_name, last_name, email_address) VALUES (1, 'Peter', 'Parker', 'peterparker@mail.com')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

And this is my simple html form:

```
<form action="core/try.php" method="post" />

<p>Nome persona: <input type="text" name="person_id" /></p>
<p>nome <input type="text" name="first_name" /></p>

<p>cognome <input type="text" name="last_name" /></p>
<p>email <input type="text" name="email_address" /></p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

What have I done wrong?!

Comment: Remove your original DB cridentials. Never show it in any site.

Comment: @RaviHirani here the OP is asking to test if it's a connection issue or otherwise, perhaps better to suggest that he/she change the credentials after the question is solved ;)

Comment: Please create a table named 'persons' in database.

Comment: @flacle: He wrote mysqli_connect_error() and also mysqli_error(). So it is enough to know errors.

Comment: @RaviHirani he didn't provide the actual error, it's a free account and he explicitly provided his credentials to let verify if it's actually a connection issue or otherwise. Under certain circumstances it's okay to show credentials IMO, but maybe this does go against the [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal)?

Comment: @RaviHirani I've just posted them because it's only a try, that's not my real database ;)

Comment: @fiacle: It's not that case. Cool :)

Answer (score -1):

From the connection settings and code that you've provided it seems that the table `persons` does not exist or is missing. I can only see the table `tabella`. I think you have to create the table `persons` first. Connecting to the database itself with the code that you've provided works. This is the error that I'm getting:

```
ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO persons 
(person_id, first_name, last_name, email_address) 
VALUES (1, 'Peter', 'Parker', 'peterparker@mail.com'). 
Table 'sql2107307.persons' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Ok, I have modified it into $sql = "INSERT INTO tabella (person_id, first_name, last_name, email_address) VALUES (1, 'Peter', 'Parker', 'peterparker@mail.com')"; but it returns me the same error: ERROR: Could not connect. Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sql2.freesqldatabase.com' (110)

Comment: @user3042848 can you add the error you getting from your PHP log? I still see only the ``tabella`` table, changing ``persons`` to ``tabella`` in your code works for the INSERT statement.

Comment: The error is "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sql2.freesqldatabase.com' (110) in [HOST A]/core/try.php on line 6
ERROR: Could not connect. Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sql2.freesqldatabase.com' (110)" . Now I've created the table "persons" but I'm still getting that error.

Comment: @user3042848 hmm maybe there is a device between you and the server that blocks your connection. Can you telnet to 3306 on that server's IP address?

Comment: I don't know, HOST A is my website host, I think I can't telnet from it

Comment: Old question, but how could you decide a missing table was a problem from "Can't connect to MySQL server"? I suggest deleting this so the question can get cleaned out by Roomba.

Comment: @miken32 don't understand the downvote, if you read the question carefully it becomes apparent that I've managed to connect to the database with the credentials provided by the OP. Connecting to the database did work and I got a different error, which led us to believe that at least the credentials were not the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You have not used the password and username you were given when you created the sqldatabase, check from your email the details